# What are the ways to rollback ECS deployment to previous successful state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, containers, amazon-ecs

I have a containerized application, which I want to deploy to AWS ECS Fargate. This deployment is orchestrated through GitHub Actions, which triggers the execution of a CloudFormation script responsible for updating the ECS service.

I've enabled the ECS circuit breaker functionality, which has its advantages. However, a practical challenge I'm facing is that in the event of container startup failures, it leads to a significant delay of approximately 30-40 minutes for the CloudFormation process to terminate. This delay arises due to the circuit breaker's activation requirement of a minimum of 10 failed tasks.

https://blog.cloudglance.dev/deep-dive-on-ecs-desired-count-and-circuit-breaker-rollback/index.html

I followed the steps from the guide to expedite the deployment process, and it has proven effective. However, there's a trade-off involved. In order to achieve this improvement, I need to set the Desired Count to 10, which in turn initiates 10 task instances. This approach doesn't align perfectly with my initial intentions

I'll explain the flow:

1. Whenever a new code is pushed to the application repository, it triggers a GitHub action.
2. This action initiates the creation of a fresh Docker image, which is subsequently uploaded to the Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR).
3. Following this, the GitHub action proceeds to run a CloudFormation stack.
4. Within the CloudFormation stack, updates are made to resources such as AWS::ECS::Service and AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition in the existing AWS stack.
5. As a result of these changes, AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS) tries to create a new revision of the task definition. However, complications arise during this step – the container fails to initiate due to a code-related issue(Errors)
6. ECS tries to restart the container multiple times. After encountering 10 consecutive failed attempts, the status of the new task definition is marked as "failed." 10 because deployment circuit breaker is active.
7. Regrettably, this cycle of 10 attempts spans an excessive duration of around 30 to 40 minutes, which is clearly unacceptable

To address this challenge, I explored an approach by adjusting the DesiredCount parameter. While initially setting it to 10 did result in a faster identification of failure (due to all 10 instances failing at once), it introduced another issue. Specifically, in deployments where creation of the new task definition revision is successful, this approach launches 10 instances of the task, a result that is contrary to the desired outcome. Therefore, the this strategy is not optimal.

Comment: What specifically are you asking for? A way to tune how ECS circuit breaker works? A way to manually rollback a deployment? Something else?

Comment: Hello @MarkB,

I've edited the description of the post. Please view the updated one.

Thank you

Comment: Your edit just described in more detail how ECS circuit breaker works, which we already know. You didn't clarify what exactly you are asking for help with.

Comment: I want to somehow reduce the time it takes to transition service to FAILED state so the deployment fails quickly when buggy code is deployed

Comment: You have no other options to tune the way the deployment circuit-breaker works. If you were using any other tool than CloudFormation to perform the actual deployment step, you could probably add in something like an `aws ecs` command in your CI/CD pipeline that would time out your deployment much sooner, but since you are using CloudFormation I think you are stuck with the way CloudFormation works.

Comment: @MarkB What could you suggest me if I did not use CF? I would like to hear it

Comment: I personally prefer Terraform over CloudFormation. Or you could use an AWS CodePipeline that uses AWS CodeDeploy for the deployment to deploy directly to ECS instead of updating a CloudFormation stack.